# Pass object data to upper object property

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a array list which is bellow and want to assign a value from bottom to up.

**Code sample:**

```
var tempArrayList=[
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:null,org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:null,org4:null,org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:"head1",org2:null,org3:null,org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"}
];

for(var i=0;i<tempArrayList.length;i++) {   
    var temp=tempArrayList[i];
    var org1=temp.org1;
    var org2=temp.org2;
    var org3=temp.org3;
    var org4=temp.org4;
    var org5=temp.org5;
    
    document.write(JSON.stringify(temp));
    document.writeln("<br>");  
}
```

**My Questions:** how can I set the org2 value to org1, org3 value to org2......

> // if org1 is null then temp.org1 = temp.org2, temp.org2 = temp.org3, temp.org3 = temp.org4, temp.org4 = temp.org5
>
> // if org1 and org2 is null then temp.org1 = temp.org3, temp.org2 = temp.org4, temp.org3 = temp.org5, temp.org4 = null

Comment: So to be clear move to left whenever null exists so all null will be at end?

Comment: How many `org`s there could be? Are they always in a sequence (if there is `org4` then `org3` is there for sure)?

Comment: @charlietfl, yes all null will be at end.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir, i do not know how many org is there but it has sequence org1,org2....

Comment: Do you need to modify the original object or is a new one fine? `tempArrayList.map( temp => Object.assign( ...Object.values( temp ).filter( v => v ).map( ( v, i ) => ( { [ "org" + ( i + 1 ) ]: v } ) ) ) )`. For each element of the array, it grabs the values, removes falsey (null) ones, then collapses back into an object.

Comment: What would happend to the last `org`s after their value have been assigned to previous `org`s?

Comment: @vox, I do not want to modify original object.

Comment: It looks like those objects really should have been arrays.

Comment: @Bergi Has a good point, since you want values to "move up" that indicates that order of the object keys is important. Since there is no specification in ES about getting the object keys in any particular order you have to provide the keys in the order you want them to be. I added an answer that can do this but you'd be better off if the elements in `tempArrayList` were arrays since arrays do have a certain order.

Comment: @HMR The order seems to be by number, not by occurence. So to iterate the object, I'd use `for (var i=1, key; (key="ord"+i) in obj; i++)`

Comment: @Bergi Yes that would work assuming the member names (keys) always go by this naming convention and no members on prototype. I think if you pass an array of keys it'll be more robust. The function uses partial application (closure) for `reason` and `keys` so you'll get a function back that can be used for particular object types that shift for particular reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter all the null out of values array then loop over keys and assign filtered value or null

```js
var tempArrayList=[
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:null,org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:null,org4:null,org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:"head1",org2:null,org3:null,org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"}
];

tempArrayList.forEach((o) => { 
   const vals = Object.values(o).filter(v => v);           
   Object.keys(o).forEach((key, i) => o[key] = vals[i] || null);
});



console.log(tempArrayList)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100%!important;}
```

Comment: This code (Object.values,  const) do not support to my application, can you provide pure JavaScript code?

Answer (score 1):

Accepted answer fails on falsy values (`{org1:false}`), mutates original object and falsely assumes `Object.keys` returns in a particular order.

There is no guarantee in the order `Object.keys` returns the array of keys in the right order:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

> in the same order as that provided by a for...in loop

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

> A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order

If the code with `Object.keys` works then try it again but add this first:

```
tempArrayList = tempArrayList.map(
  x => 
    Object.keys(x).reverse().reduce(
      (acc,key) => {acc[key]=x[key];return acc;}
      ,{}
    )
);
```

Here is one solution to the problem that doesn't rely on Object.keys order, does not mutate and does not fail on falsy member values:

```js
const collapse = function(direction,reason,subject,seed,keys){
  if(Array.isArray(subject)){
    keys = (function(x){
      const ret = [];
      while(++x<subject.length){
        ret.push(x);
      }
      return ret;
    }(-1));
  }
  keys =
  (direction>0)
    ? keys
    : keys.reverse();
  const sortedKeys = keys.filter(
    function(key){return !reason(subject[key])}
  ).concat(
    keys.filter(
      function(key){return reason(subject[key])}
    )
  );
  return keys.reduce(
    function(acc,key,index) {
      acc[key] = subject[sortedKeys[index]]
      return acc;
    }
    ,seed
  );
}

const collapseLeft = function(reason,keys){
  return function(seed,subject){
    return collapse(1,reason,subject,seed,keys);
  }
};

const collapseRight = function(reason,keys){
  return function(seed,subject){
    return collapse(-1,reason,subject,seed,keys);
  }
};


const tempArrayList=[
  {org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
  {org1:null,org2:null,org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
  {org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:null,org4:null,org5:"Pay"},
  {org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
  {org1:"head1",org2:null,org3:"Pay",org4:null,org5:null}
  ];  
const isNull = function(x){return x===null;};
console.log(
  tempArrayList.map(
    function(item){
      //seed can be an object ({}) or array ([]) see other log
      return collapseLeft(
        isNull,
        ["org1", "org2", "org3", "org4", "org5"]
      )
      ({},item);
    }
  )
);

//collapse right example
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    collapseRight(
      isNull,
      ["org1", "org2", "org3", "org4", "org5"]
    )({},{org1:"head1",org2:null,org3:"Pay",org4:null,org5:null})
    ,undefined
    ,2
  )
);

//array example (seed is [])
console.log(
  JSON.stringify(
    collapseRight(isNull)([],[1,2,3,null,4,null,5])
    ,undefined
    ,2
  )
);
```

Comment: Wow, that looks complicated. I'd recommend plain `if` statement over those ternaries.

Comment: I think the problem is not with the return value of the `if` or that it has "block"  result, but the empty case. It's just unidiomatic to write `keys =   (direction>0) ? keys : keys.reverse();`, especially with the in-place `reverse`.  `if (direction <= 0) keys.reverse()`

Comment: Btw, how would you have written it in F#? I don't know F# but only some other MLs, and I'd imagine that `keys` is an immutable variable not a parameter that is repeatedly overwritten.

Comment: @Bergi Maybe separate functions with nested match expression. Match subject with type array -> true return [0.1,2,3 ... subject.length] / not type array return keys. Then match direction and ret.urn keys or keys.reverse(). But would not have subject be an object or array but a union type.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

This code loops through the object keys, moving the values up and setting the last one to `null`.

```
var tempArrayList=[
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:null,org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:null,org4:null,org5:"Pay"},
{org1:null,org2:"Office",org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},
{org1:"head1",org2:null,org3:null,org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < tempArrayList.length; i++) {
    var keys = Object.keys (tempArrayList[i]);
    for (var j = 0; j < keys.length; j++) {
        if (j < keys.length - 1) {
            tempArrayList[i][keys[j]] = tempArrayList[i][keys[j + 1]];
        } else {
            tempArrayList[i][keys[j]] = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shohel Sorry, it didn't work at first, but it should be now I've updated it. You may need to reload the page to see the updated answer.

Comment: not working brother, try for this record {org1:null,org2:null,org3:"HR",org4:"Payroll",org5:"Pay"},